# Sharing an audio using ShareLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-sharelink, sharelink

Does anyone know how we can share a track(I have the URL, but I will download it, so consider I have the Data the I got from URL session) using ShareLink in Swift, that also has an image attached to it(I believe music apps use GIF sometimes)? Any example is highly appreciated. I cannot find any that shows how we can share an image/video alongside an audio file using share link. I want to share it to instagram stories so it can be played there.

I managed to fetch the Data and download an mp3, but I cannot share it with an image, and even when I try to share the mp3 alone, and click on share it fails. I want the effect of how we share a track from Spotify or other music apps there, which has an image/gif attached to it as well.

A good example of what I am looking for is Spotify or any other music app, you can share a track with an image as its background. How can I achieve that in Swift?

I just want an example to see the process and how it works. Thanks!

Here is a quick mock that I made, I am not using good networking calls or programming principles, just quickly made up something to make it more clear what I am looking for:

```
public struct Audio: Transferable {
    /*
     I already have the image in my asset, and I fetched the mp3 from my network call, how can I share them both so they work like music apps
     */
    public static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(exportedContentType: .mp3) { audio in
            audio.data
        }
    }


    public var data: Data
}

class GetData {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func fetch(_ url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .retry(1)
            .tryMap { data, response in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse) // or any other appropriate error
                }
                return data
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getData(completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
        fetch(URL(string: "https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-3s.mp3")!)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    print("Request completed successfully.")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                }
            }, receiveValue: { data in
                // Handle the received data
                print("Received data: \(data)")
                completion(.success(data))
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

public struct ShareView: View {
    @State var data = GetData()
    @State var mp3Data: Data? = nil
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Fetch Data") {
                data.getData { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        // Handle the received data
                        print("Received data: \(data)")
                        mp3Data = data
                    case .failure(let error):
                        // Handle the error
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            if let mp3Data {
                let audio = Audio(data: mp3Data)
                ShareLink("share me", item: audio, subject: Text("subject"), message: Text("message"), preview: SharePreview("preview"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is guide that explains how to use ShareExtension in iOS to share content outside your app.https://medium.com/@aakashstha/understand-and-implement-share-extension-conversation-suggestions-in-swift-for-ios-a6956d7d8722

Comment: @GinderSingh Thanks for providing the link. But this article is not using the ShareLink which is SwiftUI, instead it is using UIKit and is not talking about sharing an audio using it. My goal is to find out how to share an audio with a background image from my app to instagram stories, like you can do on Spotify. For example, on Spotify, if you click on share a track, you can share the audio and it's image, and that is what I am trying to find out how to do.

Comment: I have added an answer which uses ShareLink + SwiftUi to share a mp3 files with preview image.

Comment: @GinderSingh Thank you for your response Ginder. Perhaps my question was not clear enough, I will update it. But I am trying to export the actual file, not just the URL. Take a look at how music apps to that for example. Spotify, Youtube music and etc are some examples. When you click on share, they provide a nice visual image or video(perhaps a GIF), and the audio with it. I doubt they are sharing the URL there. It looks like a dynamic image that comes with sound.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work.

- Add file.mp3 to your project.
- Add "preview" file to your asset catalog
- Run following code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Audio: Transferable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let previewImageName: String
    let audioUrl: URL
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        ProxyRepresentation(exporting: \.audioUrl)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let audio = Audio(title: "Cool audio", description: "Save this audio", previewImageName: "preview", audioUrl: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "mp3")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ShareLink(
                item: audio,
                preview: SharePreview( audio.title, image: Image(audio.previewImageName, label: Text(audio.description))))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```